# Dashed arrow without dashed head after export

Tags: graphics

I was playing with the `Arrow` primitive and needed to draw a dashed arrow, as in

```
Graphics[{Dashed, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]
```

However, when exporting the figure to a pdf file with `Export` or even with the "Save Graphic As..." menu produces an image in which the arrow's head has a dashed border, which is (correctly, I think) not visible in Mathematica.

To better check the effect, just increase the arrow's head

```
Graphics[{Dashed, Arrowheads[1], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]
```

and enlarge the graphics.

I'm using Mathematica 12.3 on a Mac.

Is this a bug or something that can be fixed?

--- EDIT

It appears that the problem only occurs with vector formats (pdf, svg, ...), but not with raster formats (GIF, JPEG, ...).

The first image is what you correctly obtain with a raster format (GIF), while the second one shows a dashed border around the arrow's head after exporting to PDF.

[image: Correct image in GIF format]

[image: Incorrect image with dashed border in PDF format]

Comment: it would be nice if you can attache an image.

Comment: I believe this is a known (& older) issue, but I cannot recall the precise wording of the QA that this potentially duplicates.

Comment: @valarmorghulis Added two images illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior comes from the assigned style `Dashed` where it makes the edge of the head of the arrow dashed too. I tried `EdgeForm[None]` but still there, so as a workaround you can add a dashed line while keeping the arrow out like this

```
Graphics[{{Arrowheads[1], Arrow[{{0.99, 0.99}, {1, 1}}], Dashed, 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}}]
```

and this is how the picture in the pdf looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. It is, however, a bit unfortunate to have to compute the coordinates of the {0.99,0.99} point, which is easy to do here, but less comfortable in more complex scenarios. So I'll wait for more solutions some more time before accepting this one. BTW, is this a confirmed Mathematica but, then?

Comment: I meant Mathematica bug, of course